# Htaccess allow end with dot

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am migrating from IIS to Apache, now I am having trouble configuring the htaccess.

When a url ends in a dot, htaccess ignores it, but when it only includes a dot between the url, htaccess allows it.

Example:

> /test. becomes /index.php?page=test

> /te.st becomes /index.php?page=te.st

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I use Windows server, NGINX with Apache

Comment: What you want is probably not directly possible; https://stackoverflow.com/a/60109807/1427878 refers to a bug report on Apache’s behavior, that appears to still be open. _“Apache strips all trailing dots and spaces unless the path segments is exactly "." or ".."”_

Comment: I am using `Apache/2.4.46` and `/test.` is being capture in `$_GET['page']`

Comment: Thanks @CBroe it looks like it is an apache problem on windows.